# Changing JScrollPane height in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I failed to change the height of `JPanel` or `JScrollPane` to make more lines to appear, I used `GridLayout`. It seems that, every component in it should have the same size even when I use `setSize()`. Should I use another layout?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Main {

   private JFrame mainFrame;
   private JLabel headerLabel;
   private JLabel statusLabel;
   private JPanel controlPanel;
   private imagePanel image;

   JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

   public Main() throws IOException{
        prepareGUI();
   }


   class imagePanel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
       try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("file.jpg"));
            g.drawImage(image, 170, 0, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
   Main swingControlDemo = new Main();  

  swingControlDemo.showEventDemo();      

   }

   private void prepareGUI(){
  mainFrame = new JFrame("Java SWING Examples");
  mainFrame.setSize(400,500);
  GridLayout gridlayout = new GridLayout(4, 1);
  gridlayout.setVgap(1);
  mainFrame.setLayout(gridlayout);

  headerLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER );
  statusLabel = new JLabel("",JLabel.CENTER);        

  JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(statusLabel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

  mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
        System.exit(0);
         }        
      });    
  controlPanel = new JPanel();
  controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  image = new imagePanel();
  image.setLayout(new FlowLayout());



 // mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
  mainFrame.add(image);
  mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
  mainFrame.add(scroller);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }

   private void showEventDemo(){
  headerLabel.setText("Control in action: Button"); 

  JButton okButton = new JButton("reload");
  JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
  JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");

  okButton.setActionCommand("reload");
  submitButton.setActionCommand("Submit");
  cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");

  okButton.addActionListener(new ButtonClickListener()); 
  submitButton.addActionListener(new ButtonClickListener()); 
  cancelButton.addActionListener(new ButtonClickListener()); 

  controlPanel.add(okButton);
  controlPanel.add(submitButton);
  //controlPanel.add(cancelButton);     
  controlPanel.add(textField);
  System.out.println("---------------------");
  mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
   }

   private class ButtonClickListener implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     String command = e.getActionCommand();  
     if( command.equals( "reload" ))  {

             statusLabel.setText(convertToMultiline("Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4\nLine5\nLine6\nLine7\nLine8\nLine9\nLine2\nLine3\nLine\nLine2\nLine3\nLine\nLine2\nLine3\nLine\nLine2\nLine3\nLine\nLine2\nLine3\nLine\nLine2\nLine3\nLine\nLine2\nLine3\nLine"));

     }
     else  {
        statusLabel.setText("Submit Button clicked.");
     }      
  }     
   }

   public static String convertToMultiline(String orig)
   {
       return "<html>" + orig.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
   }
}
```

[image: Run application]

The GUI need to look like this

[image]

Comment: *"Should I use another layout?"* Probably, or a combination of layouts. Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g) {
       try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("file.jpg"));
            g.drawImage(image, 170, 0, null);` There is a whole lot wrong with even those 4 lines of code..

Comment: I want to remove the large vertical gaps between the componets, and the jLabel should use that space.

Comment: *"I want to.."* ASCII art or a drawing tells it a lot more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to remove the large vertical gaps between the componets, and the jLabel should use that space

Well in your comment you say you want the label to use the space. But in your picture you show the text area with all the space. How can we answer a question when you give us conflicting requirements? Be specific and accurate when describing a problem.

In any case, the default layout of a `JFrame` is a `BorderLayout` so you would probably start with that.

Then the component that you want to grow/shrink as the frame is resized should be added to the `CENTER` of the frame.

Then you create a second panel to contain your other components. This panel would then be added to either the `PAGE_START` or `PAGE_NORTH` of the frame depending on your exact requirement.

The layout manager of this panel can then be whatever your want. Maybe a GridLayout, or a GridBagLayout or a vertical BoxLayout.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on Layout Managers for more information and working examples. The key point is you create nest panels each with a different layout manager to achieve your layout.

Comment: Sorry if that was not clear, but the JLabel in this case is the text area, and it is the only used JLabel object in the code.

Comment: @Ahmed, well as I said "in any case" and then provided you with the answer. So is the problem solved?